# Restricting (Age-Protecting) a UIWebView to avoid 17+ user rating

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store-connect

Recent policy changes with iTunes Connect mean that any application which gives "unrestricted" access to the internet (via `UIWebView`) must have a `17+` rating.

I have such a feature in my app, but it is a very non-critical feature. Rather than removing it all together, I wondered if there is a way to have an age protection around these features to avoid needing the `17+` rating.

For example: could I require Facebook login and check the user's age?

Has anybody had success with techniques like this?

Comment: I think  Ruby Mewmew more than answered your question. Do you have any specific needs? Why would you need unrestricted web access and at the same time not having to comply with that guideline? It is obvious you could do age filtering, but it is more probable that Apple rejects your app just because of that (it could smell fishy to the reviewer and they tend to reject apps in those cases). Could you explain your problem better?

Comment: My point is that I want to be able to disable the feature for those who are not of-age, thus making my app available to a wider audience, while preserving the feature for those to whom it is applicable. The answers so far do not accomplish this, though they are decent "middle-ground" solutions (i.e., water down the features by scrubbing the searches).

Answer (score 1):

I've had to use UIWebView in an app before and the best way around it is to restrict it to what it can do. Do you need to give the users wide access to the web or just your site? I simply made a little 10 minute mobile port and mapped it so there was no external site access.

I doubt a Facebook login would satisfy Apple but unrestricted means giving the UIWebView full access to the web by putting in a URL bar or a search box to Google.

Comment: You probably won't even need to make it protected from trying to get on the web; Apple don't brute test your app for every possibility.

Comment: Simply removing a URL/search bar actually is sufficient for Apple. But my feature requires a search bar.

Comment: You could try and lock it to a child friendly search engine.

Comment: I upvoted though I don't understand your last sentence. "But unresticted means with a URL bar"?? Coul you rephrase it?

Comment: Is that okay? Basically I mean an unrestricted webview is a webview where the user can get access like you'd have with Safari