# Can the first page of an iPhone application be a web view that requires user to log in?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on an iPhone application that needed to replicate an Android application that uses a web page as its login screen which comes right at the beginning of the application. I went through some articles, but failed to see if apple will be ok or if it will not be ok with the first page being a web page. Does anyone have more details on this front?

Comment: Also see how using a UIWebView can affect your age rating if you're not careful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574590/restricting-age-protecting-a-uiwebview-to-avoid-17-user-rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many apps require a login at startup. So this will probably be ok for your app as well, even if it's a web view.

You must however supply a test account Apple can use. You provide this test account to Apple when you want to submit your app to the App Store in iTunes Connect.